# Rules for “mindestens”

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure, numbers

Is one of those sentences wrong?

> Ich muss mindestens bis 15:00 arbeiten.
>   Ich muss bis mindestens 15:00 arbeiten.

I’d intuitively say that *bis* after *mindestens* is wrong, but on the other hand, I’d usually not even notice this use if someone speaks to me.

Answer (score 5):

Both are correct. In

> Ich muss mindestens bis 15:00 arbeiten.

*mindestens* refers (or could refer) to the whole sentence, in

> Ich muss bis mindestens 15:00 arbeiten.

it refers only to *15:00*. In this case there is little difference in meaning.

Comment: Thanks for the response. What do you mean by "refers to the whole sentence"? I guess the intention behind the sentence is clear - so if there's a difference in meaning, which version is off?

Comment: @NikolajK: I mean grammatically. *Mindestens* is an adverb. Wikipedia says *An adverb is a word that modifies a verb, adjective, another adverb, determiner, noun phrase, clause, or sentence.* So, in this context, I meant *mindestens* modifies the whole sentence.

Comment: @NikolajK: The more I think about it the less I think it's true. But certainly placing it between *bis* and *15:00* ties *mindestens* closer to *bis 15:00*. As I said, there is no (or close to no) difference in meaning.

Comment: Compare: "well, at least I have to work until 15:00", and  "Well, I have to work until at least 15:00".